# Find module corresponding to the method in python

Tags: python, pytorch

I am learning to work with fastai. And I come across this:

```
xt = tensor(3.).requires_grad_()
xt
[out1]: tensor(3., requires_grad=True)
```

I want to know where `requires_grad_()` is from i.e., is it from `fastai` or is it `pytorch` related. So I do:

```
requires_grad_.__module__
[out2]: NameError: name 'require_grad_' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: `requires_grad_` isn't any sort of globally-known name, it's an attribute of the `tensor` object.  That class is what you should be looking at to locate the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Err

**The key is you cannot access `requires_grad_` directly.** `requires_grad_` is **not a global object**, it is a **member method** of `xt`, so you cannot access it directly (when you do this, you'll get  the `not define` error),  the way to access it is through the class instance it belongs to (`xt`), like `print(xt.requires_grad_.__module__)`.

### Test

According to doc on [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), all of function, member method, class and class instance have `__module__` attr. So the code `print(xt.requires_grad_.__module__)` should work, but when I tested the code

```py
print(xt.requires_grad_.__module__)
```

and got output `None` rather than `torch` I expect, which is a litte bit wierd. I guess for torch Tensor's member method, this `__module__` varible is unavailable. So then I tested another case (print the `__module__` attr of a member method for another class `DataFrame`):

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
a = DataFrame()
a.min.__module__
```

and I got output `pandas.core.frame` which means we do can get `__module__` attr from a member method object.

However, in you case, the fastest way is to get the module of `xt`, since a class method must belongs to the module of its class instance, so you can just use

```py
print(xt.__module__)
```

and you will get correct module name: `torch`.

BTW, `requires_grad_` belongs to torch.Tensor which belongs to torch module, at backprop phase, this func set a bool flag that tells torch whether gradient of tensor `xt

Comment: Thanks. So when I want to understand where a `member method` (`requires._grad_`) is coming from the BEST I can do is look at where the object (`xt`) is coming from? correct?

Comment: For member method, it is. Sorry, I had a wrong understanding of `__module__` attr before. After checking official doc , I revise the part about which objects has `__module__` attr in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you are able to access something with a dot (`.`), like:

```
x.y
```

it means that `y` is a valid **attribute** of either the type of `x`, or a valid **attribute** of the particular object to which the name `x` points.

The **attribute** `y` can **only** be referenced with the dot-notation. That is why, here `y.__module__` gives you an error.

Note that here I'm using the term **attribute** in a generic sense where even a method defined in a class is considered an **attribute** of the class.